# NestJs GET by ID not working when tested with Postman

Tags: mongodb, http, postman, nestjs

I have a function to retrieve a book given an id, this is the method in the book service file:

```
async findBookById(id: string): Promise<Book> {
  try {
           const bookFounded = await this.bookModel.findById(id);
           return bookFounded;
      } catch (error) {
           throw new HttpException("Book not found!",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
}
```

And this is how I call the book service method in the book controller:

```
@Get(':bookId')
async findBookById(
    @Param('bookId') bookId: string
): Promise<Book> {
    return this.bookService.findBookById(bookId);
}
```

When I test it with Postman if the Id is correct it prints out the book info, if the Id is different in length it throws the not found exception as it should but when the Id is altered it still gives me a 200 OK status code without showing any book info:

example the Id is: 1234fr4s2

if I check with: 1234fr4s (I removed the last '2') it gives me 404 not found (so this works fine)

if I check with: 1234fr4sf or 1234fr4s4 it does not show any book info but still gives me 200 Ok status.

Why this behaviour?

Comment: You missed to put await in the method call this.bookService.findById() (In your controller file), that may cause for this issue

Comment: @BennisonJ it's fine to return the promise directly without awaiting. The await may lead to a cleaner error message, or allow a `try/catch` to enact, but it wouldn't cause the result to be empty